# Problem with NOT LIKE query in MySQL

Tags: mysql

i want to make a selection that excludes the entries that start with 07, 0256 and 0356.
this is what i tired:

`SELECT * FROM rapoarte WHERE nrtel NOT LIKE '07%' OR nrtel NOT LIKE '0256%' OR nrtel NOT LIKE '0356%'`

but it keeps selecting all the entries.

Comment: Switch `OR` with `AND` and you're good to go.

Comment: thanks, i don't know why i've never thought of that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The condition `nrtel NOT LIKE '0256%' OR nrtel NOT LIKE '0356%'` is always true (unless nrtel is NULL). You need to use AND:

```
SELECT * FROM rapoarte
WHERE nrtel NOT LIKE '07%' 
AND nrtel NOT LIKE '0256%'
AND nrtel NOT LIKE '0356%'
```

Or you could rewrite it as follows if you find it easier to read:

```
SELECT * FROM rapoarte
WHERE NOT (
   nrtel LIKE '07%' OR 
   nrtel LIKE '0256%' OR 
   nrtel LIKE '0356%'
)
```

The expression `(NOT a) OR (NOT B)` is not the same as `NOT (a OR b)`. See [De Morgan's Laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Comment: (NOT A) OR (NOT B) == NOT ( A AND B )

Comment: the queries work in mysql, but not in PHP. i don't get any results.